# Script is supposed to loop through subnet in powershell with false ips in the mix

Tags: powershell

```
cd filepath

$Fullip = “10.2.xx.”
For( $i = 1x -lt 2xx){
$psIPAD = $Fullip + $i

 }



$psVar1 = .\HPQLOCFG.exe -S $psIPAD -F filepath |Select-object -unique| Select-object -Last 1 -Skip 2
$psVar2= .\HPQLOCFG.exe -S $psIPAD -F filepath |Select-Object -unique| Select-Object -First 1 -Skip17
$psVar3= .\HPQLOCFG.exe -S $psIPAD -F filepath |Select-Object -unique| Select-Object -First 1 -Skip19
$psVar4= .\HPQLOCFG.exe -S $psIPAD -F filepath |Select-Object -unique| Select-Object -First 1 -Skip21
$psVar5= .\HPQLOCFG.exe -S $psIPAD -F filepath      |Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 64
$psVar6= .\HPQLOCFG.exe -S $psIPAD -F filepath      |Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 65
$psVar7 = .\HPQLOCFG.exe -S $psIPAD -F filepath      |Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 66
$psVar8 = .\HPQLOCFG.exe -S $psIPAD -F filepath      |Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 76
$psVar9 = .\HPQLOCFG.exe -S $psIPAD -F filepath      |Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 77
$psVar10 = .\HPQLOCFG.exe -S $psIPAD -F filepath      |Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 78


if ($psVar1 -match "ON"){$psVar1   = "ON"}else{  $psVar1   = "HOST POWER IS OFF !" }
if ($psVar3 -match "non"){$psVar3 = "failure"}else{   $psVar3  = "Redundant"    }
if ($psVar4 -match "Balanced"){$psVar4  = "Balanced"}else{  $psVar4  = "This isn't set to balanced!"}
if ($psVar5 -match "1"){$psVar5  = "Power Supply 1"}else{  $psVar5  = "Man Down! On power supply 1!!"}
if ($psVar6 -match "yes"){$psVar6  = "Yes"}else  {  $psVar6  = "This power supply is not detected!!"}
if ($psVar7 -match "good"){$psVar7  = "Good, In use"}else  {  $psVar7  = "Not in use!"}
if ($psVar8 -match "2"){$psVar8  = "Power supply 2"}else  {  $psVar8  = "Man Down! On power supply 2!!"}
if ($psVar9 -match "yes"){$psVar9  = "Yes"}else  {  $psVar9  = "This power supply is not detected!!"}
if ($psVar10 -match "good")   {$psVar10 = "Good, In use"}else  {  $psVar10 = "Not in use!"}



$psIP      =  "IP Address             : " + $psIPAD
$psName    =  "Host Name              : "
$psPower   =  "Host Power             : " + $psVar1
$psWattage =  "Wattage is at          : " + $psVar2
$psRED     =  "Power System Redundancy: " + $psVar3
$psHE      =  "High Efficency Mode    : " + $psVar4
$psL1      =  "Label                  : " + $psVar5
$psP1      =  "Present                : " + $psVar6
$psStat1   =  "Status                 : " + $psVar7
$psL2      =  "Label                  : " + $psVar8
$psP2      =  "Present                : " + $psVar9
$psStat2   =  "Status                 : " + $psVar10


"$psIP 
 $psName 
 $psPower  
 $psWattage 
 $psRED  
 $psHE  
 $psL1  
 $psP1  
 $psStat1 
 $psL2 
 $psP2  
 $psStat2"  | Out-File -FilePath P:\root\ResultFolder\Fingers1.txt
```

I need to make sure this doesnt break when it hits an old ip that no longer exists and for it to keep looping and writing to the folder till it hits the last increment. I dont believe the i is incremented right or maybe im used to ++ and I think the loop is supposed to encase this entire thing.

Comment: have you tried running just your `for` loop with the `$I` send to the screen? that loop won't  work. once you fix that, then simply add a `Test-Connection` for the IP to see if it is responding.

Comment: I would borrow the [Get-IPRange script on the script repository](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-the-IP-addresses-in-a-60c5bb6b) to get a list of IPs, and then run `Test-Connection` against the entire range to see which ones respond. Then loop the rest of your script against that.